# What's the advantages of using barrier function in optimization

Tags: optimization

I'm new to optimization. I saw that Interior point optimization technique uses barrier function. I also know barrier function is a continuous function whose value on a point increases to infinity as the point approaches the boundary of the feasible region of an optimization problem. I saw that using barrier function I can remove inequality constraints. But I'm not getting the advantages of using Barrier function.Can you help me to understand?

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Read http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01040-7/S0273-0979-04-01040-7.pdf